# Find repeats with certain length within a string using python

Tags: python, regex, loops, mismatch

I am trying to use the [regex](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#search-vs-match) module to find non-overlapping repeats (duplicated sub-strings) within a given string (30 char), with the following requirements:

1. I am only interested in non-overlapping repeats that are 6-15 char long.
2. allow 1 mis-match
3. return the positions for each match

One way I thought of is that for each possible repeat length, let python loop through the 30char string input. For example,

```
string = "ATAGATATATGGCCCGGCCCATAGATATAT" #input

#for 6char repeats, first one in loop would be for the following event:

text = "ATAGAT"
text2 ="(" + text + ")"+ "{e<=1}" #this is to allow 1 mismatch later in regex

string2="ATATGGCCCGGCCCATAGATATAT" #string after excluding text

for x in regex.finditer(text2,string2,overlapped=True):
    print x.span()

#then still for 6char repeats, I will move on to text = "TAGATA"...
#after 6char, loop again for 7char...
```

There should be two outputs for this particular string = "**ATAGATATAT**GGCCCGGCCC**ATAGATATAT**". 1. The bold two "ATAGATATAT" + 1 mismatch: "ATAGATATATG" &"CATAGATATAT" with position index returned as (0,10)&(19, 29); 2. "TGGCCC" & "GGCCCA" (need add one mismatch to be at least 6 char), with index (9,14)&(15,20). Numbers can be in a list or table.

I'm sorry that I didn't include a real loop, but I hope the idea is clear...As you can see, this is a very less efficient method, not to mention it would create redundancy --- e.g. 10char repeats will be counted more than once, because it would suit for 9,8,7 and 6 char repeats loops. Moreover, I have a lot of such 30 char strings to work with, so I would appreciate your advice on some cleaner methods.

Thank you very much:)

Comment: Can you add an input and expected output to make your question more clearly?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @Kasra AD, I just did some edits and hope it is a little more clear now. Input is string, and output is repeats with position index.

Comment: The thing you haven't explained is what a "repeat" is.  Is "ATAGATATAT" a repeat?  If so, why?  Only some of those letters are repeated.  Why isn't "GGGGGGG" a repeat?  That seems pretty repeated.  What makes something a "repeat"?

Comment: @Helene welcome, now i'll be grateful if you answer to Brionius's question too!

Comment: @Brionius  thanks for your responses --- I'm sorry I missed the GGGG part, and just did some more edits. Yes that is a repeats.

Comment: @KasraAD Yes Brionius is correct, I missed that one. Just edited the post again.

Comment: @Helene, do you absolutely need to use regexes? Seems like it would be easier to loop through the string a few times algorithmically.

Comment: Hi @StanislavShabalin no I do not have to use regex. What algorithm you suggest please?

Comment: I don't understand the exception you've created to the no-overlap rule - could you explain that?

Comment: @Brionius Sorry for the confusion. So for example in "AATAATGGAATAATAAT", the first AATAAT is a repeat with two AATAAT fragments (one right after GG, one is  the end of the string).  Even there are overlapping between the later AATAAT fragments, they are individually paired with a non-overlapped fragment in the beginning, so they are fine. I will delete that sentence in my post, because it is actually not conflict with the normal role of non-overlap, which would be the pair of repeats in one incidence overlap with each other.

Comment: So you're saying as long as the repeat doesn't overlap with the first incidence of the substring, it counts as a repeat?

Comment: @Brionius not quite, since I'm looking for a pair of repeats to be returned each time, I'd like this pair not to overlap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try straightforward algorithm instead of regex (which are quite confusing in this instance);

```
s = "ATAGATATATGGCCCGGCCCATAGATATAT"

def fuzzy_compare(s1, s2):
    # sanity check
    if len(s1) != len(s2):
        return False

    diffs = 0
    for a, b in zip(s1, s2):
        if a != b:
            diffs += 1

        if diffs > 1:
            return False        

    return True

slen = len(s) # 30
for l in range(6, 16):
  i = 0
  while (i + l * 2) <= slen:
    sub1 = s[i:i+l]
    for j in range(i+l, slen - l):
        sub2 = s[j:j+l]
        if fuzzy_compare(sub1, sub2):
            # checking if this could be partial
            partial = False
            if i + l < j and j + l < slen:
                extsub1 = s[i:i+l+1]
                extsub2 = s[j:j+l+1]
                # if it is partial, we'll get it later in the main loop
                if fuzzy_compare(extsub1, extsub2):
                   partial = True

            if not partial: 
                print (i, i+l), (j, j+l)

    i += 1
```

It's a first draft, so feel free to experiment with it. It also seems to be clunky and not optimal, but try running it first - it may be sufficient enough.

Comment: Thank you @StanislaveShabalin . I tried out your code and I agree that it makes the concept more clear than using regex. However I noticed that the repeats in the very middle "TGGCCC" & "GGCCCA" with 1 mismatch is not called out. Also, how would you suggest to solve the redundancy please? since the partial regions of the longest repeats would be counted as smaller repeats. I'm working on these right now, but just want to keep you posted. Thanks.

Comment: @Helene, " "TGGCCC" & "GGCCCA" with 1 mismatch is not called out"

How does that have 1 mismatch? I see 2: T & G in the beginning and C & A in the end.

Comment: @StanislavShablin Thanks so much for the update. You are right about the mismatch --- I guess I'm too used to the genetic sequencing view of things. Don't worry about it for now. I will mark yours as the answer. Thank you.

Comment: @Helene, no problem, ask away if there're still any problems!